# How do you add an error loop to VBA Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create an automated form in Word and am almost done but I cannot figure out how to get an error message to pop up if a date is entered incorrectly and then to loop back to the question until it is answered correctly. Can anyone help me with this?

This is what the code currently looks like for the date entry:

```
Sub mStartDate1()

vStartDate1 = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the Start Date (dd/MMM/yyyy) and click ok.")

On Error Resume Next
   ActiveDocument.FormFields("bkStartDate1").Result = vStartDate1

Call mStartTime1

End Sub
```

When an error occurs, I currently have it going to the next field but I would like it to present an error message and then loop back to the question until it is answered correctly.

Comment: The first step is taking out `On Error Resume Next`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if a date has been submitted using the [`IsDate` Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9(v=vs.90).aspx).

You can loop until an actual date has been entered using a [`While... Wend` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264682.aspx). Once a date has been entered, convert this date into the format you require for processing.

```
Private Sub GetDate()

    Dim dateInput As Variant

    While Not IsDate(dateInput)
        dateInput = InputBox("Insert date.")
    Wend

    dateInput = Format(dateInput, "dd/MMM/yyyy")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. How do I get it to allow the date to be entered in more than one format such as dd/MMM/yyyy or ddMMMyyyy, etc..

Comment: Glad it helped! If it's answered your question then you're best marking this as the answer. To recognise a date without punctuation would require a different method - you're best asking a new question about that.